# Rails 4 Refile and mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refile

I am using refile gem to upload documents. Documents once uploaded are then sent to some recipients by email.

1) How can I add to mail as attachments the documents stored with refile ? below it is not working

I have the following in DB:

```
commented_id, varchar
commented_filename, varchar
commented_size, varchar
commented_content_type, varchar
```

attach files:

```
@revisions.each do |revision|
  mail.attachments["#{revision.file_filename}"] = File.read(revision.file)
end
```

> error: no implicit conversion of Refile::File into String

2) Can I change dynamically location of store files?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to attach files to mailers from the objects individually inside my application_mailer.rb file by calling read on the file directly, rather than using #read as a File class method. I'm using ActionMailer in rails and the mailer method looks like this, assuming that `revision` is the database object that has the `commented` file attached as described in your db:

```
def send_mailer(revision)
   @revision = revision

   attachments["filename_here"] = @revision.commented.read
   mail(to: "email@email.com", subject: "Here's your file!")
end
```

Not sure if you're using ActionMailer as well but if you are, this might work!